# Pre-calculus - Deriving position from acceleration

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

Suppose an object is dropped from the tenth floor of a building whose roof is 50 feet above the point of release. Derive the formula for the position of the object *t* seconds after its release is distance is measured from the *roof*. The positive direction of distance is downward and time is measured from the instant the object is dropped. What is the distance fallen by the object in *t* seconds?

The problem gives you acceleration as being **$a=32$**. I integrate to velocity, getting **$v=32t + C$**. At the time of release, $v=0$, so the equation is **$v=32t$**. Integrate again for position and I get **$$s=16t^2 + C$$**
Here is where I get stuck. Do I add 50 to the position function because the height is measured from the roof? What is the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add $50$ft to the function, because when $t=0$, the object is $50$ft away from the roof.

Answer (score 0):

Also the second time you integrate you get

$$s = 16t^2 + Ct + C_2$$ - you get a new constant for each new integration. So it is this $C_2$ that you can help determine from the initial condition ( height at $t = 0$ ).

A monomial $t^n \rightarrow \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}$ under differentiation. So if $n = 1$ you see we get $$t^1 \rightarrow \frac{t^{1+1}}{1+1} = \frac{t^2}{2}$$
and for $n=0$ we get: $$t^0 \rightarrow \frac{t^{0+1}}{0+1} = t$$